# Yii 2.0 : how to set different rules on same attribute for different scenerio

Tags: php, yii2

I need to validate a file field in **yii 2.0**. My rule for file field 'name' looks like this.

```
[['name'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty'=>FALSE, 'extensions'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'maxSize'=>'1024']
```

I have two scenarios insert and update. For insert, I need `'skipOnEmpty'=>FALSE` and for update I need `'skipOnEmpty'=>TRUE`.

How can I achieve this in Yii 2.0?

Comment: In 1.1 there used to be `'on' => 'scenario'`, so you can repeat same rule with different scenario. Don't know how about 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make 2 validation rules with required scenarions:

```
[['name'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty'=>FALSE, 'extensions'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'maxSize'=>'1024', 'on'=>'insert']
[['name'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty'=>TRUE, 'extensions'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'maxSize'=>'1024', 'on'=>'update']
```

and in your controller when you initialize model, set required scenario:

```
$model = new Product;
$model->scenario = 'update';
```

official docs:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html